# Determine which layer in a raster stack is first to meet a condition?

Tags: r, function, raster, r-raster

I want to analyze a raster stack and determine the first layer in the stack that meets a condition for every pixel.

```
# Generate stack of random values
library(raster)

r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <-r5 <- r6 <- r7 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1[] <- rpois(ncell(r1), 1)
r2[] <- rpois(ncell(r2), 1)
r3[] <- rpois(ncell(r3), 1)
r4[] <- rpois(ncell(r4), 1)
r5[] <- rpois(ncell(r5), 1)
r6[] <- rpois(ncell(r6), 1)
r7[] <- rpois(ncell(r7), 1)

# stack them
s <- stack(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7)
```

I want to take this stack and determine the first layer to meet a condition like: "Value = 1 for 3 consecutive layers" or "2 of last 3 layers have value = 1", for example.

Can you think of any function to do this?

If I run rasterToPoints I can convert the stack into a dataframe with columns representing each layer value. This may make things easier.

```
values<-as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(s))
values<-values[,3:ncol(values)]  #eliminates two columns at the beginning
values$first<-NA
```

At this point I think I would want to loop through and fill in the values$first column with the first column meeting my condition.

Once I determine the correct layer for each pixel, I then want an output raster with that correct layer number as the value for each pixel.

I'd appreciate any help!

Somewhat similar question posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232296/counting-layer-number-of-raster-stack-with-value-under-some-conditions-and-write), though that's counting the number of layers that meet a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that can do this for a vector and then use it in `raster::calc`.

For example, to find the first layer that has a value of 3

```
f <- function(x) which(x == 3)[1]
```

(and handles the case that none of the values is 3 well, by returning `NA`)

For example

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
f <- function(x) which(x == 255)[1] 
x <- calc(s, f)
plot(x)
```

Comment: That's useful, thanks! Can you think of any way to reference multiple layers of the stack, though? Like to find three layers in a row that equal 3, for instance?

I've gotten around this for now by running rasterToPoints to make a dataframe, and then a while loop on that.

Comment: You need to write a function that does that for a vector; and then use that with `calc` (as I show above).